# After entering a number in input field, check if that number exist on a list in react hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks, use-state

I am learning reactjs and react hooks, through my project

> points per player in a basketball match

I want the app do the following:

1. enter a number in the input field
2. check if that number already exists
3. if yes: add 1, 2, 3 to totPoints, depending on which button is clicked
4. if no: add the number and either and totPoints = 1, or torPoints = 2, or totPoints = 3. Depending on which button is clicked

2a)
2b ) if no: add the number and either and totPoints = 1, or torPoints = 2, or totPoints = 3. Depending on which button is clicked

I´m rewriting my code after idea got from youtube

```
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
  const [totPoints, setTotPoints] = useState(0);
  const [scorers, setScorers] = useState([
    {id: nanoid(4), number: 9, totPoints: 99},
    {id: nanoid(4), number: 1, totPoints: 11},
    {id: nanoid(4), number: 15, totPoints: 9},
  ]);

const onePointScoredHandler = () => {
    const players = [...scorers];
    const existingScorer = players.find((player) => player.number === number);
    if (existingScorer) {
      console.log('exist');
    } else {
      console.log('new');
    }
```

Unfortunately, `if(existingScorer)` does not recognize the numbers that are already on the list, but `console.log ('new')` no matter what number I enter in the input field

Comment: I need to know how do you set the number. The code you put seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because your `number` state is a string, while `player.number` is a number. you can use `+` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to convert it to number to properly compare them:

```
const existingScorer = players.find((player) => player.number === +number);
```

Comment: Now I want to move on with my app if existingScorer is true, I want to add to that players previous total points with this code
`if (existingScorer) {
      console.log('exist');
      existingScorer.totPoints = setTotPoints((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      setScorers(existingScorer);
    }`
Unfortunately, it does not work:
totPoints is undefined & get a non iterable error

[https://github.com/peter-swe/indiv-points]